# Animate an animation's speed

Tags: swiftui

I want the effect of a rotating record ***that has some ease to it*** whenever it **starts and stops rotating**. In code below the trigger is the `isRotating` Bool.

But I guess it's not possible to animate the speed of an animation?

```swift
struct PausableRotatingButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  var isRotating: Bool
  @State private var speed: Double = 1.0
  @State private var degrees: Double = 0.0
  var foreverAnimation: Animation {
    Animation.linear(duration: 2)
      .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
      .speed(speed)
  }
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    VStack {
      Text("speed: \(speed.description)")
      configuration.label
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: degrees))
        .animation(foreverAnimation)
        .onAppear {
          degrees = 360.0
        }
        .onChange(of: isRotating) { value in
          withAnimation(.linear) {
            speed = value ? 1 : 0
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

struct TestRotatingButtonStyle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    TestRotatingButtonStyle()
  }
  struct TestRotatingButtonStyle: View {
    @State private var isPlaying: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Button {
          isPlaying.toggle()
        } label: {
          Text("")
            .font(.system(size: 200))
        }
        .buttonStyle(PausableRotatingButtonStyle(isRotating: isPlaying))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `.easeInOut` animation?

Comment: @George_E The goal is to animate the animation's `.speed` value from 0.0 to 1.0. And that's not working at all... also not with `.easeInOut`...

Comment: @TD540 What do you mean ".easeInOut" is "not working at all"? There is the .timingCurve API and listening to GeometryEffect progress as options, but a preset timing curve "not working at all" sounds pretty odd and interesting.

Comment: If you want a wheel rotation to speed up and then speed down, .timingCurve, .easeInOut, and custom .springs have worked for me. Speed is simply an API that works on a system duration vs. a user specified duration.

Comment: Not saying `.easeInOut` doesn't work. I meant its speed value isn't animatable. The goal was to have a continuous linearly rotating record, that gradually speeds up on start when `isPlaying` becomes `true`, and gradually slows down on stop  while `isPlaying ` gets toggled `false`.

Comment: Ah, that's clearer. Sounds easy. Just set a timer to continuously increment a counter. Use another boolean to swap the Animation itself. Similar to a nil-kill to a repeatForever animation.

Answer (score 1):

If `.easeOut` and `.spring` options don't cut it, you can make a timing curve. This function accepts x and y values for two points (c0, c1).

These points define anchors that (choose a mental model verb: stretch/form/define) a cubic animation timing curve between the start and end points of your animation. (Just like drawing a path between 0,0 and 1,1. If this still sounds like gibberish, look at the objc.io link below for visuals.)

```swift
Image("wheel")
.animation(.timingCurve(0, 0.5, 0.25, 1, duration: 2))
```

An ease-in-out type curve could be `.timingCurve(0.17, 0.67, 0.83, 0.67)`
https://cubic-bezier.com/#.42,0,.58,1

You can read more via the objc.io guys.
https://www.objc.io/blog/2019/09/26/swiftui-animation-timing-curves/

#### Edit re: comment on speed

While timing is the intended API, you might be able to change speed in response to a binding from a GeometryEffect progress reporter.

In the animation below, I apply or remove the shadow beneath the ball based on the progress of the vertical-sin-wave-travel GeometryEffect. The progress value is between 0 and 1. (Takeoff/flight/landing is achieved by another boolean and animation curve for x-axis offset.)

[[image: Dumbo movie effect1]

```swift
/// Ball
     .modifier(BouncingWithProgressBinding(
                currentEffect: $currentEffectSize, // % completion
                axis: .vertical,
                offsetMax: flightHeight,
                interationProgress: iteration
            ).ignoredByLayout())
```

```swift
struct BouncingWithProgressBinding: GeometryEffect {
    
    @Binding var currentEffect: CGFloat // % completion
    var axis: Axis
    var offsetMax: CGFloat
    var interationProgress: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { interationProgress }
        set { interationProgress = newValue }
    }
    
    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        let progress      = interationProgress - floor(interationProgress)
        let curvePosition = cos(2 * progress * .pi)
        let effectSize    = (curvePosition + 1) / ( .pi * 1.25 )
        let translation   = offsetMax * CGFloat(1 - effectSize)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { currentEffect = CGFloat(1 - effectSize) }
        
        if axis == .horizontal {
            return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation, y: 0))
        } else {
            return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: translation))
        }
        
    }
}
```